# ¿Is there a way to call a class method on every controller action?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core-3.0

I'm implementing a cache system to handle my JWT on server side to emulate a Session State , everytime an action is called i must validate the token on the server cache to see if it's still valid, is there a way to create a something like

```
[Authorize] or [AllowAnonymous]
```

To search over the request and do whatever is needed to valide it? i already have a singleton class that handles the cache system, all i need is an easy way to call the right methods.

I want to avoid calling via Dependency Injection the method on every action on every method.

I'm using Net Core 3.0, Distributed Cache, and a Web API with JWT validation.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use middleware, take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234135/#53242694) (scroll down for asp.net core 3.0) for an example.

Comment: Did you tried Filters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.0 ?

Comment: so dumb on my part, just a silly question, if i add a middleware is there a way to avoid the filter with some conditions? for example i don't need to validate the session once you are triying to do login, thanks.

Comment: You can't skip the middleware if that's what you mean. But you can check for a certain condition inside the middleware, e.g. `if (context.User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated = true)`.

Comment: thank you both, i used both solutions but i feel that i have more control with the filter solution, is there a way to vote both of you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement an Action Filter. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.0#action-filters) for more details