# Ignore authorization at development environment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm recently migrated from ASP .NET Core 2.2 to 3.1, everything works fine but I have an issue with ignoring authorization on Dev environment.

The code that I used in CORE 2.2:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    //On Development - ignore authorization
    services.AddMvc(opts => { opts.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter()); })
       .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
else 
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

This obviously doesn't work on CORE 3.1 but I can't find any equivalent code that works.

Among other things, I tried to use this code (below) with no result.

```
 services.AddControllers(opts =>
 {
     if (env.IsDevelopment())
     {
         opts.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter());
     }
     else
     {
     }
 });
```

Please help me with this.

My relevant code (CORE 3.1):

```
public void InstallServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger logger)
{
    services.AddControllers(opts =>
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            opts.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter());
        }
        else
        {
        }
    });

    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
    var jwtSettings = new JwtSettings();
    configuration.Bind(nameof(JwtSettings), jwtSettings);
    services.AddSingleton(jwtSettings);
    var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = jwtSettings.PrivateSigningSecretKey,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
    services.AddSingleton(tokenValidationParameters);

    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
        });
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(Authorizations.RequireAdminOrManagerRole,
            policy => policy.RequireRole(Authorizations.Admin, Authorizations.Manager));
    });
    //deleted Swagger setup
}
public void InstallConfiguration(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration, ILogger logger)
{
    //deleted Swagger setup
    app.UseHttpsRedirection(); 
    app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that works for me.
Let me know if you have a better solution

My Configuration:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection(); 
app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));
app.UseRouting();
if (env.IsStaging() || env.IsDevelopment())
{
    //on staging/development dont require authentication
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        // Set claims for the test user.
        var claims = new[] { new Claim("role", "Admin"), new Claim("sub", "some guid") };
        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "DebugAuthorizationMiddleware", "name", "role");
        // Add the test user as Identity.
        context.User.AddIdentity(id);
        // User is now authenticated.
        await next.Invoke();
    });
}
else
    app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
```

Credit:
[Programmatically add [AllowAnonymous] attribute to all my controller methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53242694/11747294)